# How to assign new attributes into spark Dataset in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Assuming I have a `Dataset<Person> personList`, that contains list of `Person`.

`Person` is defined as follows:

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    String gender;
}
```

Now I have the list `personList` as dataset, but I need to backfill another attribute into `Person`, let's say it's `age`. So I can update my `Person` to

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    String gender;
    int age;
}
```

How do I loop through the Dataset and upate the age value?

I tried this approach, but it didn't update anything:

```
    personList.foreach(person -> {
        person.setAge(12);
    });
```

I tried to give every `Person` in the `personList` age of 12, but when I read the data set, the `age` value is still empty.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map function to update a custom object, then .set() the desired value:

```
    Encoder<Person> personEncoder = Encoders.bean(Person.class);
    List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(
            new Person("John", "Doe", 25),
            new Person("Jane", "Doe", 30)
    );
    Dataset<Person> personListDs = session.createDataset(personList, personEncoder);

    personListDs.show();
    Dataset<Person> updatedPersonListDs = personListDs.map((MapFunction<Person, Person>) person -> {
        person.setAge(12);
        return person;
    }, personEncoder);

    updatedPersonListDs.show();
```

**Very important**, the Person class should have no args constructor:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    private int age;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String name, String gender, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want the age value as a variable you can just created before the .map and called it inside .map

```
final int age = 12;
Dataset<Person> updatedPersonListDs = personListDs.map((MapFunction<Person, Person>) person -> {
    person.setAge(age);
    return person;
}, personEncoder);
```

If you don't want the variable to be final, you can use a braodcast variable:

```
int age = 12;
Broadcast<Integer> broadcastAge = new JavaSparkContext(session.sparkContext()).broadcast(age);

Dataset<Person> updatedPersonListDs = personListDs.map((MapFunction<Person, Person>) person -> {
    person.setAge(broadcastAge.value());
    return person;
}, personEncoder);
```

Comment: This requires type `Row`, but my dataset type is `Person`

Comment: @OPK Sorry I didn't pay attention, I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, i think we are getting close, but not quite yet. Here is what the complier is saying: `Ambiguous method call. Both
map
(Function1<Person, Person>,
Encoder<Person>)
in Dataset and
map
(MapFunction<Person, Person>,
Encoder<Person>)
in Dataset match`.  Any idea?

Comment: @OPK I forgot how much type safe Java is xD, I should have tested it before, I updated my answer with a tested code.

Comment: Thank you. I think we are very close to get this answer accepted. One last question, what if I don't want to hard code the age value, instead I want to pass an arg into the lambda so the age value can be set dynamically? Is it doable?

Answer (score 0):

Either import object like you do know and use it to access method:

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;

    df.withColumn("foo", functions.lit(1));
```

or use import static and call method directly:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit;

df.withColumn("foo", lit(1));
```

Comment: This requires type `Row`, but my dataset type is `Person`